# total number of group homomorphism from Z2×Z2 to S3

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

G=Z2 ×Z2 has 5 subgroup and all are normal.so H1={(0,0)},H2={(G)} and H3= three sugroup of order 2.then i took the factor group and only one group homomorphism is coming.am i correct...or if i am wrong then pls help
G/H1 is isomorphic to z2×z2 but s3 has no subgroup of order 4
G/H2 is isomorphic to z1 and s3 has subgroup of order 1
In this way only one homo is coming
How to proceed further

Answer (score 5):

Counting homomorphisms and counting normal subgroups are not the same thing, so no, this method does not work.

Instead, let $a,b \in G = \mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ be generators of the two factors, so:

- $a,b$ commute with each other;
- $a,b$ are each of order 2, so they generate subgruops $\langle a \rangle$, $\langle b \rangle$ which are cyclic of order 2;
- $G$ can be written as an internal direct product $G = \langle a \rangle  \times \langle b \rangle$.

A homomorphism $f : G \to S_3$ is completely determined by its two values $f(a),f(b)$, which we can think of as an ordered pair $(f(a),f(b))$ in the set $S_3$. Furthermore, a choice of the ordered pair $(f(a),f(b))$ determines a homomorphism if and only if $f(a),f(b)$ each have order 1 or 2 and they commute with each other.

Let's list the elements of $S_3$ of order $1$ or $2$: the identity $e$ is the only element of order $1$; and there are three elements of order 2, namely $(12)$, $(13)$, and $(14)$.

The ordered pair $(f(a),f(b))$ therefore has values in the 4 element set $\{e,(12),(13),(23)\}$. The total number of choices of the ordered pair is therefore $4^2=16$.

But the fact that $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ must commute puts restrictions on the choice of the ordered pair: $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ cannot take on different values in the subset $\{(12),(13),(23)\}$ because no two elements of that subset commute with each other. That rules out $3 \cdot 2 = 6$ choices of the ordered pair. All other choices are allowed because they all commute.

So altogether there are $16-6=10$ homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2 \to S_3$.

Comment: Thnx...can we apply fundamental theo of homo

Comment: I presume you are asking about the theorem that for any surjective group homomorphism $f : G \to Q$, the group $Q$ is isomorphic to $G$ modulo the kernel of $f$. That's what you tried to use in your answer, by counting normal subgroups. And that's what I said does not work.