# What is the significance of homomorphism mapping generator element to identity?

Tags: group-homomorphism

In response to the below problem:

How many homomorphisms from $K_4\rightarrow D_3.$

Have doubt:
Am not clear, why is a map of order $2$ element $\in K_4,$ possible to $e?$

---

<strike>The group table for $K_4$ is:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
&e&x&y&xy\\ \hline
e&e&x&y&xy \\ \hline
x&x&e&xy&y \\ \hline
y&y&xy&e&x \\ \hline
xy&xy&y&x&e \\ \hline
\end{array}</strike>

In $K_4,$ the order of all non-trivial elements is $2,$ and product of any two such elements is another non-trivial element in the group.
Also, any two elements commute with each other.
Say, $xy = yx.$

So, must map $\phi(a),$ for non-trivial element $a\in K_4,$  to an order $2$ element in $D_3.$

In $D_3,$ all reflection elements are of order $2.$
The two non-trivial rotation elements have order $3,$ as:
$\langle R\rangle
=\{R, R^2, e\},$ 
$\langle R^2\rangle
=\{R^2, R, e\}.$

The group table for $D_3$ is:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
&e&R&R^2&T&TR&TR^2\\ \hline
e&e&R&R^2&T&TR&TR^2 \\ \hline
R&R&R^2&e&TR&TR^2&T \\ \hline
R^2&R^2&e&R&TR^2&T&TR  \\ \hline
T&T&TR&TR^2&e&R&R^2 \\ \hline
TR&TR&TR^2&T&R^2&e&R \\ \hline
TR^2&TR^2&T&TR&R&R^2&e \\ \hline
\end{array}

So, can map any non-trivial element $\in K_4,$ to any reflection element $\in D_3.$
But, need $\phi(a)\phi(b)= \phi(b)\phi(a),$ for $a,b\in K_4.$
But, that is impossible in $D_3,$ if $\phi(a)\ne \phi(b),$ unless $\phi(a)=\phi(b),$ or $\phi(b)= e.$

Say, $TR\cdot TR^2= R,$ but $TR^2\cdot TR = R^2.$

$TR\cdot T= R^2,$ but $T\cdot TR = R.$

Hence, have $3$ choices for any element $a$ to map to. 
Corresponding to each such choice, have $2$ choices for $\phi(b).$
This leads to $3\cdot 2= 6$ choices.

Next, consider the trivial map  $\phi(a)=e.$ And, $\phi(b)$ can map to either $e,$ or any reflection element.
$\phi(a)= e,$ for any of the four choices available for the element $a,$
The possible choices are:

1. $\phi(a=x)= e, \phi(b=y)= e,$
2. $\phi(a=x)= e, \phi(b=y)= T,$
3. $\phi(a=x)=e, \phi(b=y)=TR,$
4. $\phi(a=x)= e, \phi(b=y)= TR^2.$

Due to the commutativity of $ab\in K_4,$ need only consider the map of one element $a,$ i.e. $\phi(a)= e. $
Else, had need to consider four more cases.

In total have $6$ non-trivial maps of generator element $\phi(a),$ and $4$ trivial maps of $\phi(a)$ in $K_4.$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [total number of group homomorphism from Z2×Z2 to S3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2057002/total-number-of-group-homomorphism-from-z2%c3%97z2-to-s3). There are exactly $10$ group homomorphisms from $K_4=\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$ to $D_3\cong S_3$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Seems not, as the doubt is not addressed.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Also, cannot edit the post, to make it different from the suggested one. Reason is made the post for doubt only. Hence, detailed the logic in detail, to highlight that the doubt is still not addressed.

Comment: Then you should change the title. We already know the answer to this title question. Rewrite the title and the post about what you really want to address. You can use that $D_3 \cong S_3$, if this is easier. And can you explain your doubt more clearly? Of course I can map an element of order $2$ to the neutral element. Just take the trivial homomorphism mapping everything to $e$, for example.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Hope need not remove the solution, and edit is fine. Doubt to your comment: I think if group $G$ has an order $2$ generator $a,$ then it is fine to map $a^2\to e,$ not $a\to e.$

Comment: @DietrichBurde In the striked-out solution in the post, have detailed the way in which got the answer. But, the trivial map $\phi(a)= e, $ or $\phi(b)= e,$ does not gel when consider only an order $2$ element in $D_3,$ for mapping generator element in $K_4.$

Comment: We can map $a\to e$, I don't see why not. I have a language problem with your "does not gel". What is a "gel"?

Comment: @DietrichBurde By that meant, it is not coherent or logical, if on one hand we need the same order element in the range, in order to map the generator $a$ in the domain to. But on the other hand, map the generator $a$ to $e,$ as a trivial map.

Comment: We do not need the same order in the range. We can map it to $e$. If $a^n=e$, then $\phi(a)^n=e$, but possibly also $\phi(a)^m=e$ for a smaller $m<n$. So the order need not be equal.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks a lot. But, what is the name of this property in homomorphism/mapping.

Comment: @DietrichBurde You seem to say that $n$ is simply a multiple of $m,$ with the smallest order of $a$ as $m.$ But, how to see this fact, from just the satisfaction of $\phi(ab)= \phi(a)\phi(b),$ by choosing ('in any possible group') $\phi(a)= e.$

Comment: @DietrichBurde Having $\phi(a^2)= e\implies \phi(a)^2= e\implies \phi(a)= e^{1/2}= e.$ Hence, can understand. The visualization ("to see") seems is possible for some special (linear) groups only, not for non-abelian group, as dihedral groups.

Comment: No, this is not true. Take the transposition $a=(12)\in S_3$ with $\phi=id$. Then $\phi(a^2)=\phi(e)=e$, but $\phi(a)=(12)\neq e$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Though, you disprove it; but cannot still be sure for $S_3,$ that don't have for the generator element $\phi(a) = e,$ in the below cases:

(1). endomorphism from $S_3 → S_3.$

(2). Homomorphism from $S_3 → Z_3.$

Request to give reference of a post, or other source; that shows the lack of trivial homomorphism for the above example, or something similar.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Have a simple proof: For any $g \in G, $ with homomorphism $\phi: G→H,$ have $\phi(g)^n = \phi(g^n),$ & $\phi(eG) = eH.$ Thus if $|g| = n,$ then $\phi(g^n) = \phi(eG) = eH,$ and $\phi(g)^n = eH,$ so $|\phi(g)|$ must divide $n.$ But, cannot see how it helps in disproving that $S_3$ lacks trivial homomorphism, in my earlier comment's two examples.